# SyntaxError: Unexpected token S in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, lambda, netlify

I have a netlify function which returns a correct data as well as success message which I call to my api. Though when I tried to show the data in my react front end it gives me error with promise status rejected.

```
Promise{pending}
[[promiseStatus]]: rejected
[[PromiseValue]]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token S in JSON at position 0
```

function which reads data from graphql 
**readWeight.js**

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch'

exports.handler = async() => {
  console.log("inside");
  const response = await fetch(
    'https://graphql.fauna.com/graphql',
    {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${API_SECRET}`
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        query:`
        {allweight{data{weight}}}
        `
      })
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
    //console.log(response.data.allweight.data.map(w=>console.log(w.weight)))
    //console.log(response)
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(response)
  }
}
```

**api.js**

```
const readAll = () => {
  return fetch('/.netlify/functions/readWeight').then((response) => {
    console.log(response)
    return response.json()
  })
}
```

api.js response

```
Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:3000/.netlify/functions/readWeight", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
type: "basic"
url: "http://localhost:3000/.netlify/functions/readWeight"
redirected: false
status: 200
ok: true
statusText: "OK"
headers: Headers {}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: true
__proto__: Response
```

***app.js***

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import api from './api'

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    weight: []
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    // Fetch all todos
    console.log(api.readAll())
    api.readAll().then((t) => {
      this.setState({
        weight: weight
      })
    })
  }
render(){
return(
<h1>Test
          {this.state.todos}</h1>
)
}


}
```

Comment: So based on your code, we can assume that this is logging something out in the `api.js` file: `console.log(response)`? What does that log out? Also, unless I'm reading it wrong, it looks like in your handle you are awaiting for the response from the GraphQL end point but then it doesn't look like you use the response anywhere?

Comment: Thanks @TomFinney i've updated code and it works.